# Sed regex in bash issues

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Can someone tell me why this sed below doesn't work

```
...| sed -E $'s/^\d/blah/g'
```

vs this one works?

```
| sed -E $'s/^/blah/g'
```

sample:

```
echo "10/30/18 04:45:13 PM EDT" | sed -E $'s/^/blah/'
```

Updated desire:

```
echo "10/30/18 04:45:13 PM EDT" | 
sed 's/^[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]\/[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]\/[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]/\blah\n/'

blah
10/30/18 04:45:13 PM EDT
```

Comment: What do you mean by "works"? You haven't provided any input, and neither expected nor actual output. I assume, from the Linux tag, that you are using GNU `sed`.

Comment: On what input? I think both sed "work".

Comment: What is this `-E $`? and what is your expected results here?

Comment: extended regex support

Comment: Gotcha. I don't have that on my version. I see the -E now on the online manuals. What is the "$"? Why not just `sed 's/^/blah/g'` here?

Comment: Well, and was does not "work" here? Both sed commands return zero return status.

Comment: @JNevill `$' '` get's expanded by bash, ex. `$'\n'` expands to newline, `$'abc\ndef'` expands to abc followed by newline followed by def. In this case it does completely nothing (and `-E` also does completely nothing...). See [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html)  3.1.2.4 .

Answer (score 0):

Property `\d` (digits) works in PCRE/Perl but not in BRE or ERE flavors that is used by `sed`.

Use `[[:digit:]]` instead of `\d` in `sed`:

```
sed 's/^[[:digit:]]/blah/'
```

---

For your updated question use this `gnu sed` command:

```
echo "10/30/18 04:45:13 PM EDT" |
sed -E 's~^([[:digit:]]{2}/){2}[[:digit:]]{2}~\blah\n&~'
```

```
blah
10/30/18 04:45:13 PM EDT
```

Comment: Thanks - this works - whats the trick to re-add those digits - ie if I wanted to look for your regex above yet before that match add some text ?

Comment: I don't get this same output:
echo "10/30/18 04:45:13 PM EDT" |sed -E 's~^([[:digit:]]{2}/){2}[[:digit:]]{2}~\blah\n&~'
blahn10/30/18 04:45:13 PM EDT

Comment: Can you try this `awk` command: `echo "10/30/18 04:45:13 PM EDT" | awk '/^([[:digit:]]{2}\/){2}[[:digit:]]{2}/{print "blah"} 1'`

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^..\/..\/.. ..:..:.. /iblah' file
```

Inserts `blah` above the regexp and:

```
sed '/^..\/..\/.. ..:..:.. /ablah' file
```

Appends `blah` below the regexp.